# iPhone 6S fingerprint reader malfunction

Tags: security, unlock, iphone, authentication

I am unable to unlock my device because it is not recognising my fingerprint. What can I do?

Comment: Clear all your fingerprints and see if you can add new ones?

Comment: How can I clear them if I am unable to unlock the phone?

Comment: You can unlock your phone with the password.

Comment: That option is not showing up, it keeps asking for fingerprint.

Comment: What iOS version?

Comment: The problem started right after I installed 10.3.2

Comment: Try using the method I've answered. That is all. Get to the widget screen. Swipe right from the lock screen.

Comment: I didnt add any widgets. The lock screen doesnt change when I swipe right, but the camera appears when I swipe left.

Comment: Notification centre? Updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

After five unsuccessful attempts to match a fingerprint your iPhone will prompt you to enter your passcode. You can also use your passcode to unlock the phone after any failed attempt.

Once you've unlocked it, do as follows:

1. Go to Settings
2. Swipe up and tap on the Touch ID & Passcode option
3. Enter your passcode
4. Tap on each fingerprint and tap on Delete Fingerprint
5. Once you've deleted them all, go back and use the Add a Fingerprint option to re-add your fingerprints
6. Exit Settings

Answer (score 0):

iOS has a failsafe with password. It's the alternative option when TouchID doesn't work. If you want to directly get into entering passcode from the lock screen.

1. Slide to the right from the **Lockscreen** to bring up the **widget menu** to list all the widgets on your device.

[image]

2. Now **click on any of the Widget** which will take you to the unlock with passcode/TouchID screen.
3. After you've unlocked your device, go remove all the fingerprint from the TouchID Settings.

Alternatively, Try opening any notification from the notification tab. Send yourself an SMS if you don't have any new notifications/Internet is turned off. Click on any notification or message to open it, which will take you to enter the password.

[image]

Comment: I have the control center disabled on the lock screen.

Comment: .. however, i can answer the phone if someone calls me, otherwise the device is a brick.

Comment: @FrankR. It does not matter that you have Control Center disabled. This is iOS 10 feature.

Comment: I got to enter the passcode using your advice, but its not accepting the passcode I assigned! I have a feeling my phone got hacked. Is there a way to reset it to factory?